# have the user implement a static method

Tags: java, android-fragments, module, static

I just created a module (in an android app) and I want to share it as a library since no one is available.

For it to work, the user needs to provide a class with 2 static methods :

- one is `static Fragment newInstance(arg1, arg2)`, and I have to set the number and type of argument,
- and the second is `static MyModel getModel()` which I call inside a Fragment.

When the user instantiate the main class of the module, he provides as an argument a class `mFragmentClass` which will be passed along. I then use reflection to invoke the static methods :

```
Method m = mFragmentClass.getDeclaredMethod("newInstance", int.class, int.class);
return (Fragment) m.invoke(null, mParent, position);
```

The `newInstance(mParent, position)` methods is static by pattern, and the `getModel()` is called inside a Fragment so it has to be static because my model is absolutely not parcelable.

But since static methods can neither be abstract nor in interfaces, how can I make the user implement these methods ?

EDIT : you can put a static method in an interface, but you have to define it and I want my user to override it.

Comment: Sorry, but *"For it to work, the user needs to provide a class with 2 static methods, which I invoke later using reflection."* doesn't sound like something one would like to have in his libraries.

Comment: Yes of course, but for this time I don't have much choices... Maybe later when I'm a better programmer. Actually I still can explain it in the Readme.md, but I would like it clean.

Comment: Why should it be static ?

Comment: Why not use an interface? I think they are perfectly suited for this

Comment: @ug_ you cannot have static methods in interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I finally get through this using an abstract class and some Exceptions.

Not the cleanest solution, but it works and I think users won't get lost.

```
public abstract class BaseChildFragment extends Fragment {
    public static Fragment newInstance(int horiz, int vert){
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "\n ------ You have to hide (override) newInstance(int horiz, int vert) in your child class ! ------"
        );}

    public static MyModel getModel(){/*idem*/}
}
```

So I learned that static methods cannot be overriden, but they can be hidden, which is the same but without the annotation and without any possible call to `super`.

The javadoc of my library tells the user to provide a class which extends BaseChildFragment and which implements these 2 classes. If he doesn't hide these classes, it throws a neat Exception, and a quick look at the javadoc will tell him what to do.